# Convert some elements to int

Tags: python, list, integer

In python i would like to convert some string elements of a list to int.

So i have:

my_list = ["car", "10", "20", "50", "60", "13", "bike"]

How to make it:

my_list = ["car", 10, 20, 50, 60, 13, "bike"]

Answer (score 6):

A simple [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will do:

```
my_list = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in my_list]
```

This uses a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and tests with [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

The `str.isdigit` check does assume that all numbers are non-negative integers. For more complex numerical strings like `"-5"` or `"1.7"` you might have to be more verbose and use a loop and possibly a broader type (`float`) in line with @Sujay's solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i, j in enumerate (my_list):
    try:
         my_list[i]=int(j)
    except ValueError:
          pass
```